# mod_proxy using .htaccess on LiteSpeed

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-proxy, litespeed

I'm trying to get this htaccess code to work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^fld/(.*) http://example.com/fld/$1?proxy=http://example.com [P]
  RewriteRule ^/?$ http://example.com/fld/app/cobra/847?remoteaddr=%{REMOTE_ADDR}&proxy=http://mydomain.com/customfolder [QSA,P]
</IfModule>
```

mod_rewrite is enabled, but I've been told that mod_proxy is not enabled/available on Litespeed.

Is there a PHP workaround to running this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was just trying the same thing on LiteSpeed and found your post.  The only way I could achieve the proxying was via a simple one-line PHP script.

```
<?= file_get_contents('http://example.com/');
```

So to do what you're doing, it would be something more like this...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^fld/(.*) proxy.php?fld=$1 [QSA,last]
  RewriteRule ^?$ proxy.php [QSA,last]
</IfModule>
```

And in `proxy.php`:

```
<?= file_get_contents(
      'http://example.com/' 
      . '?fld=' . $_GET['fld']
      . '&remoteaddr=' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
);
```

I hope that makes sense.  If your hosting provider happens to block remote URLs in this manner, you might need to use curl which is a bit more code.